# How to project a spherical panorama onto the sides of a tikz folding poyhedron?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

Amazing how simple one can put text (or anything else) onto the faces of a [polyhedron](http://nvcleemp.wordpress.com/2009/04/19/tikz-folding-adding-the-platonic-solids-and-beyond/) like this [calendar](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/foldable-dodecahedron-with-calendar/).

But how can I project a 360° spherical photo onto the sides?

I assume one should start with a [spherical projection image](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/CAVE/projects/sp_mos/pics/spherical_mosaic.jpg) which one can generate with various tools (like panotools, I think). Or one could start with a [cubic projection](http://wiki.panotools.org/index.php?title=Cubic_Projection&oldid=9402) which probably has less distortions.

**But how to position the correct image portions onto each polyhedron face?** I think one could fiddle with translating and rotating by hand a lot, but maybe there is an even simpler way -- since the rotating and translating is done already for the faces.

Comment: Do you have an example of a 360° spherical photo that you would like to display in the way you describe? The transformations required crucially depend on the type of the original image.

Comment: @Jake I have some that look similar to http://www.cs.columbia.edu/CAVE/projects/sp_mos/pics/spherical_mosaic.jpg. Although, I would happily rerun my Hugin with a http://wiki.panotools.org/index.php?title=Cubic_Projection&oldid=9402 projection, I looks as if it has less distortions.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a projection on a sphere (also possible with an eps image):

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-mirror}
\usepackage{pst-grad}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-7,-7)(7,7)
  \newpsstyle{GradWhiteYellow}{fillstyle=gradient,gradbegin=yellow,gradend=yellow!20,
     linecolor=yellow!50,GradientCircle=true,gradmidpoint=0,GradientPos={(1,1)}}%
  \pscircle[style=GradWhiteYellow](0,0){7}
  \pstSphereGrid[linecolor=red,grille=10,Ymin=-50,Ymax=50,Xmax=80,Xmin=-80,normale=0 0](20,0,0)
  \pstSphereGrid[linecolor=blue,grille=10,Ymin=-40,Ymax=-20,Xmax=80,Xmin=-80,normale=0 90](40,0,-10)%
  \pstTextSphere[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red,normale=0 0,fontscale=40,PSfont=Time-Roman,yO=0](20,0,10){pst-mirror}
  \pstTextSphere[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=black,normale=0 0,fontscale=20,PSfont=Helvetica,yO=0](20,0,35){PSTricks}
  \pstTextSphere[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue,normale=0 90,fontscale=10,PSfont=Helvetica,yO=2.5](10,0,-10){A Spherical Mirror}%
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting. Though, only about 10% the way...